# adding a image button inside a tr which is getting dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i want to add button image inside the tr i add tha code like but its show syntax error

```js
 $("#tabletask tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").html("<button class='expandcollapse'> <img src="vectorimages/align_left.svg"></button>" + OriginalContent + "")
```

what change i done here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape `"` characters in `<img>` definition:

```
.html("<button class='expandcollapse'> <img src=\"vectorimages/align_left.svg\"></button>" + OriginalContent)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `"` characters in `img` to single quotes `'`

```
 $("#tabletask tr[data-id='" + parrentid + "'] > td:first-child").html("<button class='expandcollapse'> <img src='vectorimages/align_left.svg'></button>" + OriginalContent)
```